# Throw/catch error when a variable is undefined using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'd like to know if there is any solution to throw an error when a variable is not defined inside my template?

Example:

```
function hello() {
    var data = { foo: 'hello' };

    //data.bar is undefined, data.bar will be replaced by an empty string by underscore
    var render = _.template('<p><%= data.foo %><%= data.bar %></p>', {data: data}); 

    //Rendering okay? true|false
    //if (render...)

}
```

I'd like to throw an error if the variable data.boo is not defined after the call of the _.template function. Do you have any idea if it's possible to do something like that? I checked the documentation and didn't find anything interesting unfortunately...

Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to do just seems wrong and I think your code could be refactored not to need this behaviour. Can you summarise how do you want to handle the situation when `data.foo` is undefined?

Answer (score 2):

For better or worse, Underscore will do this for you for top-level properties:

```
var data = { foo: 'hello' };
var rendered  = _.template('<p><%= foo %><%= bar %></p>', data);
// throws ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

This is because Underscore templates use `with`, so top-level properties are treated like variables. If you want an error on a sub-object property, you'll need to add it in yourself, maybe using `with` as well:

```
var data = { foo: 'hello' };
// throw
var rendered  = _.template('<% with (data) { %><p><%= foo %><%= bar %></p><% } %>',
    { data: data });
```

Or you could use an explicit `throw`, e.g.

```
<% if (data.bar === undefined) throw "No bar!"; %>
```

at the beginning of your template. But really, why would you do it this way? If you know what you're checking for, far better to do it with an explicit pre-render check and deal with it there, and avoid using errors for control flow:

```
var rendered;
if (data.foo !== undefined) rendered = _.template("...", { data: data });
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than my own.

Comment: My template is actually an HTML with several dozen of variables, that's why I wanted to avoid to test all variables separately.

Answer (score 0):

Like @mechanicalfish said, what you're attempting to do seems incorrect. You should be validating the data outside of the template. In either case, here is what you asked for:

```
function hello() {
    var data = { foo: 'hello' };

    //data.bar is undefined, data.bar will be replaced by an empty string by underscore
    var render = _.template('<p><%= data.foo %><% ' +
      '  if (!data.bar) { ' +
      '    throw "data.bar is undefined" ' +
      '  } else { ' +
      '    print(data.bar) ' +
      '  } ' +
      ' %></p>', {data: data}); 

    //Rendering okay? true|false
    //if (render...)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript has try/catch support.

```
function hello() {
    var data = { foo: 'hello' };

   try {

    //data.bar is undefined, data.bar will be replaced by an empty string by underscore
    var render = _.template('<p><%= data.foo %><%= data.bar %></p>', {data: data}); 
    } catch (e){
          throw "data.bar is undefined";
    }


}
```

Comment: The render works perfectly even though the variable is undefined, it's my problem, there is no possibility to use try/catch there.